# get unread list items count in discussion board

Tags: list, count

is it possible to get the count of unread items in list like the mailbox?

in mailbox it  shows the number of unread emails besides inbox word,

can I do the same count behavior for the unread items in discussion board list per each user and show the count in HTML div tag

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Reference: [MSDN Article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/686d411a-e1b6-4cb6-adc8-d43593365e2b/forum-faq-show-unread-items-in-sharepoint-2010-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

In order to get the count of unread items, set a counter just after the `unreadIDs+=";"+oListItem.get_item("ID")+";";` line of code in the above link and then append the counter to the HTML div using jQuery as: `$("#<div id>").append("<b>" + count + "</b>");`

Comment: thanks, i don't understand your answer, please post the full code

Comment: As the code is quite big and I'm not able to post it over here.
You can refer the full code in following  [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/686d411a-e1b6-4cb6-adc8-d43593365e2b/forum-faq-show-unread-items-in-sharepoint-2010-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment)